# C# / .NET5 IMemoryCache threw an exception of type `System.ObjectDisposedException`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net5

We migrated our web project from ASP .NET Framework 4.7.2 to ASP .NET 5

But now, for some reason, the [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) refuses to work any longer. We inject an instance into our constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache

  public MyClass(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
  {
    _memoryCache = memoryCache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
  }
}
```

And anytime we try to do an operation on that cache

```
_memoryCache.TryGetValue(_cacheKey, out object item);
```

We get an exception

> Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache'.

But we nowhere in our application call the `Dispose()` method on our cache.

FYI In our startup.cs file, we use `services.AddMemoryCache();` to have the DI.

**EDIT:**
Okay for future readers, I have managed to solve this problem for my scenario by creating my own `public class MyMemoryCache : IMemoryCache`, injecting it through `services.addSingleton<IMemoryCache, MyMemoryCache>()` and then setting a breakpoint in the `Dispose()` method that I had to implement myself to backtrack to the caller.

What we do in our application is mark some classes as a startup service, these are business classes that have to do stuff when the server starts such as filling some caches. This is all done through reflection, but in short in our startup.cs file:

```
using(var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
    foreach (var startupServiceType in _startupServiceTypes)
    {
        var startupService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(startupServiceType) as IStartupService;
        startupService.Start();
    }
 }
```

Okay now one of these services had an asynchronous method in which it scheduled stuff. The main loop however (the loop through all startup services) continued and once the `using` statement was closed, so did the `serviceProvider`. This then called `Dispose()` on all injected classes that inherited from `IDisposable` (which was only one class in our case, the IMemoryCache). The simplest solution was just nog using the keyword `using`. But I think this is also not the cleanest solution

Comment: How do you inject it?

Comment: in the constructor. We use the default dependency injection.

Comment: Please show code how do you register it.

Comment: @GuruStron It's the last line of the question...

Comment: Is it the `MemoryCache` object that is disposed or something you have put into it? I think we'd need to see a [mre] since this is pretty standard functionality.

Comment: @DavidG yep, missed that.

Comment: JIC how do you register `MyClass`? Though it usually should not affect what happens.

Comment: @GuruStron That wouldn't affect the injected memory cache object though

Comment: @DavidG yep, that is exactly what I wrote in my comment)

Comment: @GuruStron So why ask about it?

Comment: @DavidG it is the MemoryCache itself that is disposed. If it were the item itself, the error would be thrown after calling that item and not when calling the cache manager to retrieve it. I'll try with a new project to see if it can be reproduced

Comment: @DavidG im my experience sometimes in such cases when there is nothing to cause some mysterious behaviour "stupid" questions can expose some extra stuff which helps to solve the mystery)

Comment: @Everyone, I managed to find the cause. I added it to the original question in case you were interested